# How to suppress syntax inspection in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, code-inspection

I'm using PyCharm 3.4.1 and I have this piece of code in my function:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT distinct "name_{0}", code, sort_order FROM {1}'.format(get_language(), ProgrammeLevel._meta.db_table))
```

PyCharm correctly recognizes that the string contains SQL code, but the code syntax inspection informs me that I have a syntax error because of `FROM {1}`, it says: `<comma join expression> expected, got '{'`, which is a valid point, but I know what I'm doing.

For most if not all PyCharm inspections I can write a `# noinspection` comment in the right place and turn the inspection off for some piece of code. I did so, to turn off the `PyProtectedMember` inspection for the code snippet I just gave. How can I turn off the syntax inspection for this line of code? What is the inspection name to give to `noinspection` comment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is controlled with language injections rather than inspections.

To suppress the error:
`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Language Injections` and uncheck the box that says:
**`python:"SQL select/delete/insert/update/create"`**

[image: Language Injections]

---

Or, to only disable it on strings with <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> in them, change the very end of the `Places Pattern` from `.*` to `[^{}]*` like so:

```
+ pyStringLiteralMatches("[ \\t\\r\\n]*(((SELECT|DELETE) .*FROM)|((INSERT|REPLACE) .*INTO)|(UPDATE .* SET)|((CREATE|DROP|ALTER) +(TABLE|INDEX))).*")
```

To this:

```
+ pyStringLiteralMatches("[ \\t\\r\\n]*(((SELECT|DELETE) .*FROM)|((INSERT|REPLACE) .*INTO)|(UPDATE .* SET)|((CREATE|DROP|ALTER) +(TABLE|INDEX)))[^{}]*")
```

[image: pyStringLiteralMatches]